# Preview de edições sumiu

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro, edição

Quando edito uma pergunta ou resposta, não está aparecendo o preview da postagem embaixo do campo de edição. Mais alguém está tendo esse problema?

Answer (score 5):

Foi burrice minha. Não reparei num link de "mostrar visualização" logo abaixo do editor:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar no link, o preview voltou a aparecer. Provavelmente eu mandei ocultar em algum momento, e o sistema lembrou disso.

Comment: ahahahahahahahahahaha

Comment: (facepalm) ^ 64

Comment: Nunca tinha notado esse `esconder/mostrar`... Deve ter sido o *mouse bobo*; sabe quando a gente clica sem querer e não vê onde foi? Tem o *keyboard bobo* também, horas depois você aquele troço estranho no meio do código ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. Foi de propósito, para deixar a segunda-feira de vocês mais divertida `</mentira>`

Comment: É ótimo ter isso documentado no Meta, pois pode acontecer com qualquer um.

Answer (score 1):

A mim aparece.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No site principal também? Porque para mim o problema é só lá, no meta está funcionando bem.

Comment: No site principal está tudo certo pra mim. Preview aparece normalmente. :?

Comment: A mim aparece normalmente nos dois lados. Não é nenhum script manhoso que usas do SE?

Comment: Não, desliguei todos, @emanuelsn. Pode ser algum bug no javascript dos moderadores :(

Comment: Só se for, pergunta ao utluiz ou ao gabe.

Comment: E ningúem viu o `ocultar visualização` que tá bem ali no nosso nariz, jjjjj